# Confused by Siri's answer

Tags: ios, siri

I asked: "Should I wear a jacket today"

It replied: "Sorry Nathan, I can't look for places in France"

What does that mean? (Yes it's true I'm in France)

Comment: Actually, now the same question works for some reason ...

Answer (score 1):

It probably tries to look up the weather to answer that question and fails to find the weather at your location.

Comment: yet if I ask, what's the weather like? It shows me the weather at my location...

Comment: In that case I have no idea, maybe we can get a clue if someone else with a 4s asks that question and reports on what it replies.